# likewise-open issue

Tags: linux, active-directory, linuxmint, likewise-open

I've been struggling non-stop for two days on this issue and it is driving me insane. I am trying to get my Linux-Mint machine to connect to the Windows Domain so that I can gain access to the Internet, etc.

I've had a number of problems which I've sorted (DNS_ERROR_BAD_PACKET 0x0000251e, for example).

However, I am now getting:

```
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0x0000005) after waiting for around 10 seconds.
```

I can successfully join the domain when I boot into Windows 7.

Also, I cannot find much on the meaning of the above error.

My questions are as follows:

1. What does this error mean? The log in credentials are as it is on the Windows machine.
2. Is there any specific thing I should be looking for to connect to the Windows domain?
3. Is there any default configuration that possibly needs to be changed?

Comment: ...I've since tried centrify and during the addcheck it complained that the "site is not known by the AD" during the ADDSITE test. Some help will be greatly appreciated (NOTE: I like the simplicity if likewise and would prefer using it).

Comment: Does your windows account have permissions on the domain controller to add new hosts to the domain?

Answer (score -1):

For this error message, "site is not known by the AD" this means that you need to add the site in AD.  Please check your AD Sites and Services and make sure the Domain is properly set, then try the adcheck again.

By the way may I ask what version of Linux your have and what version of Centrify Express is this?  You can do adinfo -v for the version number.